# SQL Arithmetic on Specific Category/Value pairs

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns. Items in the first column represent one of four categories, and items in the second column represent the data referenced by their category counterpart:

```
CategoryA : 2
CategoryC : 1
CategoryB : 4
CategoryB : -1
CategoryD : 2
CategoryC : 1
```

etc.

I need to construct a SQL query that will return the Sum for each of these categories, e.g.

```
CategoryA : 2
CategoryB : 3
CategoryC : 2
CategoryD : 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by grouping together the relevant rows, and summing the values for each:

```
select col1, sum(col2)
  from table_name
group by col1
```

Comment: Sebastien (apologies for the lack of accent marks), I've added a little descriptive text (to hopefully make it clearer) and changed the table name (to prevent possible clashes with SQL reserved words). Hopefully that hasn't change the essence of your answer, which is right, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, SUM(column2) FROM table GROUP BY column1
```